# What do physicists mean by ${g^{i}}_j$?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, notation, tensor-calculus

Maybe this is an idiot question, but in relativity I see a lot of ${g^{i}}_j$ for a metric tensor $g$. Is this just $$\delta^i_j ~=~ g(dx^i \sharp, \partial_{ x^j})~?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  That is absolutely correct.

Comment: so why not write $\delta^i_j$ instead? It just complicate things.

Comment: @user40276: I agree that people generally should, but since you raise with the inverse metric, the two things are equivalent.